# Why my website pause at "Redirecting" after calling api many times?

Tags: linux, http, nginx

I take `Nginx` as my reverse proxy to forward the requests to websites and api. But if I call the api `many times`, the website will stop at "Redirecting" page and I have to click the url `manually`.

Here is the screen
[image]

Here is my nginx confiuration(I hidden the ssl congifuration):

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name alpha.hunghingprinting.com;
  rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}


server {
  listen 443;

  # set proper server name after domain set
  server_name alpha.hunghingprinting.com;

  # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
  add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
  proxy_set_header X-Client-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST $remote_addr;

   # SSL parameters
   ssl on;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  #   odoo    log files
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/odoo14-access.log;
  error_log       /var/log/nginx/odoo14-error.log;

  #   increase    proxy   buffer  size
  proxy_buffers   16  64k;
  proxy_buffer_size   128k;

  proxy_read_timeout 900s;
  proxy_connect_timeout 900s;
  proxy_send_timeout 900s;

  #   force   timeouts    if  the backend dies
  proxy_next_upstream error   timeout invalid_header  http_500    http_502
  http_503;

  types {
    text/less less;
    text/scss scss;
  }

  #   enable  data    compression
  gzip    on;
  gzip_min_length 1100;
  gzip_buffers    4   32k;
  gzip_types  text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript application/pdf image/jpeg image/png;
  gzip_vary   on;
  client_header_buffer_size 4k;
  large_client_header_buffers 4 64k;
  client_max_body_size 0;

  location / {
    proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:8069;
    
   # by default, do not forward anything
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

  location /longpolling {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8072;
    #proxy_pass http://odoochat;    
  }

  location ~* .(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires 2d;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8069;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
  }
  # cache some static data in memory for 60mins.
  location ~ /[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*/static/ {
    proxy_cache_valid 200 302 60m;
    proxy_cache_valid 404      1m;
    proxy_buffering    on;
    expires 864000;
    proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:8069;
  }
}
    
}
```

And if I don't use my api too many times, things are normal.

Comment: Maybe this post will help you : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290141/nginx-reverse-proxy-redirection
It suggests to turn "proxy_redirect" to on and to configure it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want nginx to rewrite the url directly you can remove this line:

```
proxy_redirect off;
```

Please check documentation: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect
Otherwise it's an issue with your browser not nginx.